# Mutiple SSL domains on one app on Heroku

Tags: ssl, heroku

I'd like to create a multitenant Rails app on Heroku. I want each tenant (user) to have its own domain with SSL. So https://user1.com and https://user4.com will both point to the same app.

I know how to [point multiple domains to one app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6360944/multiple-domains-pointing-to-single-heroku-rails-app-via-nameservers-displaying), but it [seems like it will be trickier to get multiple SSL domains pointing to one app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7552734/ssl-certificate-for-several-domains-one-ip) because the server apparently sees the IP and serves the SSL before seeing the HOST header.

Is it possible to have multiple SSL domains on one app on Heroku? How can I do it?

Comment: Check out [this answer to "Multiple SSL Certificates in One Heroku Application"](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18982770/341692).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do it, Heroku provide minimal explanation [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-endpoint#serving-multiple-domains).

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'll check it out.